# Is there a way to create columns from a list of phrases?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have lists of phrases I would like to convert into columns in a dataframe to be used as inputs for a machine learning model.  The code should find the unique phrases in all of the rows of data, create columns for the unique rows and indicate if the phrase is present in the row by showing a `1` if the phrase is present and a `0` if it is missing.

The phrases will look like the following:

```py
{"TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Kitchen", "Free Parking on Premises",
 "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom", "Heating", "Family/Kid Friendly",
 "Washer,Dryer", "Smoke Detector", "Carbon Monoxide Detector",
 "First Aid Kit", "Safety Card", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials"
 }

{"TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Air Conditioning", "Kitchen",
 "Pets Allowed", "Pets live on this property", "Dog(s)", "Heating",
 "Family/Kid Friendly", "Washer", "Dryer", "Smoke Detector",
 "Carbon Monoxide Detector", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials",
 "Shampoo", "Lock on Bedroom Door", "Hangers", "Hair Dryer", "Iron"
 }
```

Desired output in the dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Are those examples suposed to be the text you are parsing or are they already python sets? (if sets, some of the quotes are wrong). How about a smaller example of 3 or 4 components?

Comment: Can you also post the script you have so far? It helps to see where exactly there is a problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the tour and take the time to read How to Ask and the other links found on that page. Invest some time with the [Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples.

Comment: The examples are the text I will be parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the columns for the DataFrame:

```
set1 = {"TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Kitchen", "Free Parking on Premises",
 "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom", "Heating", "Family/Kid Friendly",
 "Washer,Dryer", "Smoke Detector", "Carbon Monoxide Detector",
 "First Aid Kit", "Safety Card", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials"
 }

set2 = {"TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Air Conditioning", "Kitchen",
 "Pets Allowed", "Pets live on this property", "Dog(s)", "Heating",
 "Family/Kid Friendly", "Washer", "Dryer", "Smoke Detector",
 "Carbon Monoxide Detector", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials",
 "Shampoo", "Lock on Bedroom Door", "Hangers", "Hair Dryer", "Iron"
 }

# Create a list of iterables for later
list_of_sets = [set1, set2]

# Create a list with the "splat" operator, and then create a set from the list
columns = set([*set1, *set2])

# Optionally remove spaces, commas, etc
columns_optional = set([x.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "") for x in columns])
```

Now to create the DataFrame rows:

```
def create_rows(list_of_iterables, columns):
    """Iterate through list of iterables (i.e. sets of words) 
    and check if they're in the columns"""
    
    list_of_df_rows = []
    for iterable in list_of_iterables:
        row_dict = {}
        for col in columns:
            # Set it to zero at first
            row_dict[col] = 0
            for item in iterable:
                if col == item:
                    # Change it to 1 if we found a match
                    row_dict[col] = 1
                    
        list_of_df_rows.append(row_dict)
    
    return list_of_df_rows

# Create DataFrame rows
rows = create_rows(list_of_sets, columns)

# Create DataFrame that's tall, not wide, at first
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

print(df)
>>> Air Conditioning  TV  ...  Free Parking on Premises  Washer,Dryer
0                 0   1   ...                         1             1
1                 1   1   ...                         0             0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```py
import pandas as pd

rows = [["TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Kitchen", "Free Parking on Premises",
         "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom", "Heating", "Family/Kid Friendly",
         "Washer,Dryer", "Smoke Detector", "Carbon Monoxide Detector",
         "First Aid Kit", "Safety Card", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials"
         ],

        ["TV", "Internet", "Wireless Internet", "Air Conditioning", "Kitchen",
         "Pets Allowed", "Pets live on this property", "Dog(s)", "Heating",
         "Family/Kid Friendly", "Washer", "Dryer", "Smoke Detector",
         "Carbon Monoxide Detector", "Fire Extinguisher", "Essentials",
         "Shampoo", "Lock on Bedroom Door", "Hangers", "Hair Dryer", "Iron"
         ]
        ]

header = list(set(rows[0]+rows[1]))
words_count = {}
for i in header:
    words_count[i] = []
for row in rows:
    for i in header:
        words_count[i].append(row.count(i))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=words_count, columns=header)

print(df)

# Output
   Safety Card  Hair Dryer  ...  Carbon Monoxide Detector  Shampoo
0            1           0  ...                         1        0
1            0           1  ...                         1        1

[2 rows x 26 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not asking why your code isn't working you must be asking for an algorithm. - Create a dictionary where the keys are the phrases and the values are lists with either a zero or one for each row.  A [collections.defaultdict(list)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) should help.

```
d = {'phrase1':[row1,row2,...],'phrase2':[row1,row2,...],...}
```

- iterate over the *rows* which you have shown as sets so use set operations
- for each each row

  - Find the phrases in the row that are not yet in the dictionary. This is the difference between the row and the dictionary keys - `row - d.keys()`

    - for each phrase in that difference append zeros to its value

      - for the first row append zero zeros, for the second row append one zero, for the third append two zeros...
  - Find *previous* phrases that are not in this row.  This is the difference between the dictionary keys and the row - `d.keys() - row`

    - for each phrase in that difference append a zero
  - For each phrase in the row append a one
- feed the dictionary to the DataFrame *constructor* - `df = pandas.DataFrame(d)`